# Google Play にて更新が拒否されてしまう

Tags: monaca

Google Play にて monaca を使用して Cordovaバージョン 4.1.2 でビルドしてAPKを作成し、アップロードしましたが、何度ビルドしなおしても更新が拒否されてしまうため、問い合わせたところ、

> ```
> 調査させていただきましたところ、当該アプリにおきまして、脆弱性の問題が含まれている
> 古い Apache Cordova バージョン3.6.3-2 が使用されているようです。
>
> 下記のパスにおいて問題が発生しておりますので、ご確認及び v.4.1.1 以上へのアップグレードを
> お願い致します。
>
> パス:                                      クラス:
> security/vulnerable_library/cordova/2     org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView (3.6.3-2)
> ```

との回答をGoogle Play デベロッパー サポート様より頂きました。

最初のバージョンをアップロードした時は問題なく承認され、特にビルド環境を変更することもなく、バグ修正したAPKをアップロードしたら、以後のAPKが上記理由により承認されなくなってしまいました。

どこを修正すればよいのでしょうか？

ちなみにiOSの方は問題なく承認され、公開されてています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Cordova3.5.1～4.1.0を使ったアプリがPlayストアで公開できなくなったのは先月の話( https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6325474 )のようですが、最初のバージョンをアップロードしたのはいつ頃のことでしょうか？

Comment: 最初のバージョンは 今月の11日（2016/08/11） にアップロードしました

Comment: Cordova 4.1ではGoogle playでリジェクトされてしまうので、Cordova 5.2にアップグレードする必要があります。（Cordova 5.2での動作確認、修正は再度行う必要があります）

Comment: Cordova 5.2にアップグレードしましたら、無事に承認されました

ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1):

Cordova 5.2 にアップグレードして再ビルドと申請を行ったところ、無事に承認されました。

---

この回答は [@Kadono さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28436/google-play-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a6%e6%9b%b4%e6%96%b0%e3%81%8c%e6%8b%92%e5%90%a6%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86#comment27246_28436) を元にコミュニティwikiとして投稿しました。